# C# Sql CTE Query - Select out extra information

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a CTE Recursive Query to build a tree relationship of a flat table with a 'marketGroupID' (that element's ID) and a 'parentGroupID' (the element's parent ID).  Where each 'marketGroup' can have any number of children 'marketGroups' and so on.

Here is my working query (tested in Sql Server Management):

```
    With cte As
(SELECT [marketGroupID]
      ,[parentGroupID]
      ,[marketGroupName]
      ,[description]
      ,[iconID]
      ,[hasTypes]
      , 0 As Level
  FROM [Eve_Retribution_1.0.7].[dbo].[invMarketGroups]
  WHERE [parentGroupID] IS NULL
  UNION All
  Select mg.marketGroupID
    ,mg.parentGroupID
    ,mg.marketGroupName
    ,mg.description
    ,mg.iconID
    ,mg.hasTypes
    ,c.Level + 1 As Level
  FROM [Eve_Retribution_1.0.7].dbo.invMarketGroups mg
  Inner Join cte c On mg.parentGroupID = c.marketGroupID
  WHERE mg.marketGroupID <> mg.parentGroupID
)
  SELECT marketGroupID
    ,parentGroupID
    ,marketGroupName
    ,description
    ,iconID
    ,hasTypes
    , Level
  FROM cte
```

This Query correctly lists the Elements in the correct order and the Level parameter is meant to be used to build the tree from the elements.

Translating this into C# is where I have a problem.  I have integrated this database and all the corresponding tables have been built from my database into my code automatically.  I try to call this query with C# as follows:

```
    EveOnlineClassesDataContext context = new EveOnlineClassesDataContext();
    IEnumerable<invMarketGroup> results = context.ExecuteQuery<invMarketGroup>
            (@"**ABOVE QUERY**");
```

Where the 'invMarketGroup' class is the automatically created class built by the O/R Designer.  My problem is that I lose access to the Level parameter for each 'marketGroup' as it was not part of the table itself and has no element in the provided class.

I want to retrieve from the query the actual 'invMarketGroup' class objects and the level corresponding to each so I can build a tree from this in memory representing this structure.  How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to create a [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) `vwInvMarketGroup` inside your database using that query:

```
CREATE VIEW vwInvMarketGroup AS
    With cte As
(SELECT [marketGroupID]
      ,[parentGroupID]
      ,[marketGroupName]
      ,[description]
      ,[iconID]
      ,[hasTypes]
      , 0 As Level
  FROM [Eve_Retribution_1.0.7].[dbo].[invMarketGroups]
  WHERE [parentGroupID] IS NULL
  UNION All
  Select mg.marketGroupID
    ,mg.parentGroupID
    ,mg.marketGroupName
    ,mg.description
    ,mg.iconID
    ,mg.hasTypes
    ,c.Level + 1 As Level
  FROM [Eve_Retribution_1.0.7].dbo.invMarketGroups mg
  Inner Join cte c On mg.parentGroupID = c.marketGroupID
  WHERE mg.marketGroupID <> mg.parentGroupID
)
  SELECT marketGroupID
    ,parentGroupID
    ,marketGroupName
    ,description
    ,iconID
    ,hasTypes
    , Level
  FROM cte
GO
```

Then you can use this:

```
IEnumerable<invMarketGroup> results = context.ExecuteQuery<invMarketGroup>(@"SELECT * FROM vwInvMarketGroup");
```

Comment: I was not familiar with adding views, I assume that speeds up further queries against the view?
But I do not see how I have access to the level even with this solution?

Comment: I was able to get access to the level parameter by creating the view and then using the view as the enumerable type:
`IEnumerable<vwInvMarketGroup> results = context.ExecuteQuery<vwInvMarketGroup>(@"SELECT * FROM vwInvMarketGroup");`

Thanks